# update firebase info without redrawing listview

Tags: java, android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a voting system in an android app that uses firebase as it's backend.  I'm in the process of getting the user's vote status from their history, updating the view accordingly, and responding to vote touches on the buttons.  The problem I'm having is that when a user clicks on the up or down vote buttons it redraws the listview, sometimes omitting two of the options, and always moving the scrolling of the view back up to the top.  Can I update the data inside of a listview without completely redrawing that listview?  If so, how?

**MovieActivity.java**

```
    public class MovieActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String KEY_IMDB = "KEY_IMDB";
    private ImageView mPosterImageView;
    private TextView mTitleTextView;
    private TextView mYearTextView;
    private TextView mSummaryTextView;
    private ListView triggerListView;
    private ArrayList<Trigger> mTriggerPrefList;
    private Movie mMovie;
    private LinkedList<Trigger> resultList;

    DatabaseReference movieDB;
    DatabaseReference userDB;
    DatabaseReference  thisMovieDB;
    DatabaseReference triggerDB;
    DatabaseReference adminDB;

    FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    FirebaseUser mUser;

    ArrayList<Trigger> mTriggerList;

    String imdbID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie);

        mPosterImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.posterImageView);
        mTitleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
        mYearTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yearTextView);
        mSummaryTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.summaryTextView);
        triggerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.triggerListView);


        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        movieDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("movies");
        userDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
        adminDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("admin");

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        imdbID = intent.getStringExtra("ID_KEY");
        final String keyTitle = intent.getStringExtra("TITLE_KEY");
        final String keyYear = intent.getStringExtra("YEAR_KEY");
        final String keyPoster = intent.getStringExtra("POSTER_KEY");

        try {
            getMovieDetails(imdbID, new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    CheckForTriggerValues(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            populateTriggers(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    populatePrefs(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {

                                            reOrderList(new Runnable() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void run() {
                                                    Movie passMovie = new Movie();
                                                    passMovie.setImdbID(imdbID);
                                                    passMovie.setPosterURL(keyPoster);
                                                    passMovie.setYear(keyYear);
                                                    passMovie.setTitle(keyTitle);
                                                    TriggerAdapter adapter = new TriggerAdapter(MovieActivity.this, resultList, passMovie, imdbID );
                                                    triggerListView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                                }
                                            });

                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
                thisMovieDB = movieDB.child(imdbID);
                triggerDB = thisMovieDB.child("Triggers");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putString(KEY_IMDB, imdbID);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        imdbID = intent.getStringExtra("ID_KEY");
    }

    private void getMovieDetails(String imdbID, Runnable runnable) throws JSONException {
        String apiKey = OMITTED;
        String theURL = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=" + imdbID + "&apikey=" + apiKey;
        final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(theURL).build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

                final String jsonData = response.body().string();

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                Movie movie = parseMovieDetails(jsonData);
                                updateMovieUI(movie);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

        });
        runnable.run();
    }

    private Movie parseMovieDetails(String jsonData) throws JSONException {

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonData);

            Movie movie = new Movie();

            movie.setPosterURL(jsonObject.getString("Poster"));
            movie.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("Title"));
            movie.setYear(jsonObject.getString("Year"));
            movie.setSummary(jsonObject.getString("Plot"));

            mMovie = movie;

            return movie;
        }

        private void updateMovieUI(Movie movie){
            Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
            mSummaryTextView.setText(movie.getSummary());
            mYearTextView.setText(movie.getYear());
            mTitleTextView.setText(movie.getTitle());
            Picasso.with(mContext).load(movie.getPosterURL()).into(mPosterImageView);

        }

        private void populatePrefs(final Runnable runnable) {
            mTriggerPrefList = new ArrayList<>();

            mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

            mUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

            movieDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("movies");
            userDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
            adminDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("admin");
            thisMovieDB = movieDB.child(imdbID);
            thisMovieDB.child("Details").setValue(mMovie);
            triggerDB = thisMovieDB.child("Triggers");

            userDB.child(mUser.getUid()).child("preferences").child("trigger").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    for (DataSnapshot triggerSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        String name = String.valueOf(triggerSnapshot.child("triggerName").getValue());
                        Trigger trigger = new Trigger();
                        trigger.setTriggerName(name);
                        trigger.setTriggerVotesTotal(0);
                        trigger.setTriggerVotesYes(0);
                        mTriggerPrefList.add(trigger);
                    }

                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);

                    imdbID = intent.getStringExtra("ID_KEY");
                    runnable.run();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }

            });
        }

        private void populateTriggers(final Runnable runnable) {
            mTriggerList = new ArrayList<>();
            mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            mUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

            movieDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("movies");
            userDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
            adminDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("admin");
            thisMovieDB = movieDB.child(imdbID);
            thisMovieDB.child("Details").setValue(mMovie);
            triggerDB = thisMovieDB.child("Triggers");

            triggerDB.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    mTriggerList.clear();

                    for (DataSnapshot triggerSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Trigger trigger = triggerSnapshot.getValue(Trigger.class);
                        mTriggerList.add(trigger);
                    }
                    runnable.run();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }
        private void reOrderList(Runnable runnable) {
            resultList = new LinkedList<>();

            for (Trigger triggerA : mTriggerList) {
                boolean found = false;
                for (Trigger triggerB : mTriggerPrefList) {
                    if (triggerB.getTriggerName().equals(triggerA.getTriggerName())) {
                        found = true;
                    }
                }
                if (found) {
                    resultList.add(triggerA);
                }
            }
            mTriggerList.removeAll(resultList);
            resultList.addAll(mTriggerList);

            runnable.run();
    }

    private void CheckForTriggerValues(final Runnable runnable) {
        adminDB.child("triggerList").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, Object>> genericTypeIndicator = new GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, Object>>() {};

                final Map<String, Object> triggerList = dataSnapshot.getValue(genericTypeIndicator);

                triggerDB.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : triggerList.entrySet())
                        {
                            if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(entry.getKey())){

                            }
                            else {
                                Trigger trigger1 = new Trigger(entry.getKey(), 0, 0);
                                triggerDB.child(trigger1.getTriggerName()).setValue(trigger1);
                            }
                        }
                        runnable.run();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

        int isTrue(Boolean boolDown, Boolean boolUp) {
            int x = 0;
            if (boolUp) {
                 x = 1;
            }
            if (boolDown) {
                x = -1;
            }
            return x;
        }

}
```

**TriggerAdapter.java**

```
package me.paxana.cwnet.Adapters;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.andremion.counterfab.CounterFab;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.MutableData;
import com.google.firebase.database.Transaction;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.List;

import me.paxana.cwnet.Model.Movie;
import me.paxana.cwnet.Model.Trigger;
import me.paxana.cwnet.R;
import me.paxana.cwnet.ui.AdminPanelActivity;
import me.paxana.cwnet.ui.MovieActivity;

/**
 * Created by paxie on 10/11/17.
 */

public class TriggerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Trigger> mTriggers;
    private Movie mMovie;
    private String mImdbID;
    private String mTitle;
    private String mYear;
    private String mPosterURL;

    private DatabaseReference movieDB;
    private DatabaseReference userDB;
    private DatabaseReference triggerDB;
    private DatabaseReference adminDB;


    public TriggerAdapter(Context context, List<Trigger> triggerList, Movie movie, String imdbID){
        mContext = context;
        this.mTriggers = triggerList;
        mMovie = movie;
        mImdbID = imdbID;
        mTitle = movie.getTitle();
        mYear = movie.getYear();
        mPosterURL = movie.getPosterURL();
    };

    public TriggerAdapter(Context context, List<Trigger> triggerList) {
        mContext = context;
        this.mTriggers = triggerList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.mTriggers.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return mTriggers.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, final ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        movieDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("movies");
        userDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
        adminDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("admin");

        final String mUserId = user.getUid();
        final Trigger trigger = mTriggers.get(i);

        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.trigger_list_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.triggerName = view.findViewById(R.id.triggerName);
            holder.upButton = view.findViewById(R.id.mTriggerButtonUp);
            holder.downButton = view.findViewById(R.id.mTriggerButtonDown);
            holder.total = view.findViewById(R.id.triggerCounter);

            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.triggerName.setText(trigger.getTriggerName());

        if (mContext instanceof AdminPanelActivity) {
            holder.upButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.downButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    adminDB.child("triggerList").child(trigger.getTriggerName()).removeValue();
                    int i = mTriggers.indexOf(trigger);
                    mTriggers.remove(i);
                    TriggerAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }

        if (mContext instanceof MovieActivity) {

            userDB.child(mUserId).child("changes").child(mImdbID).child("triggers").child(trigger.getTriggerName()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                        int userVote = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);

                        if (userVote == 0) {
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                holder.upButton.setBackgroundTintList(mContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorAccent, null));
                                holder.downButton.setBackgroundTintList(mContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorAccent, null));

                            }
                            else {
                                holder.upButton.setBackgroundTintList(mContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorAccent));
                                holder.downButton.setBackgroundTintList(mContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorAccent));
                            }

                            neitherButtonIsSelected(holder, trigger, mUserId);
                        }
                        if (userVote == 1) {
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                holder.upButton.setBackgroundTintList(mContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.votebuttons, null));
                                holder.downButton.setBackgroundTintList(mContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorAccent, null));

                            }
                            else {
                                holder.upButton.setBackgroundTintList(mContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.votebuttons));
                                holder.downButton.setBackgroundTintList(mContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorAccent));
                            }
                            upButtonIsSelected(holder, trigger, mUserId);
                        }
                        if (userVote == -1) {
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                holder.upButton.setBackgroundTintList(mContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorAccent, null));
                                holder.downButton.setBackgroundTintList(mContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.votebuttons, null));

                            }
                            else {
                                holder.upButton.setBackgroundTintList(mContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorAccent));
                                holder.downButton.setBackgroundTintList(mContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.votebuttons));
                            }
                            downButtonIsSelected(holder, trigger, mUserId);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        userDB.child(mUserId).child("changes").child(mImdbID).child("triggers").child(trigger.getTriggerName()).setValue(0);
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }
        holder.total.setText(String.valueOf(trigger.getTriggerVotesYes()));
        holder.upButton.setCount(trigger.getTriggerVotesYes());
        if (trigger.getTriggerVotesTotal() != 0){
            holder.total.setText(String.valueOf(trigger.getTriggerVotesTotal()));
            int downButtonCount = (trigger.getTriggerVotesTotal() - trigger.getTriggerVotesYes());
            holder.downButton.setCount(downButtonCount);
        }

        return view;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView triggerName;
        CounterFab upButton;
        CounterFab downButton;
        TextView total;
    }
    private void neitherButtonIsSelected(final ViewHolder holder, final Trigger trigger, final String mUserId) {
        holder.upButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                triggerDB = movieDB.child(mImdbID).child("Triggers").child(trigger.getTriggerName());
                triggerDB.child("triggerVotesYes").runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                    @Override
                    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                        int count = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);
                        mutableData.setValue(count + 1);
                        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    }
                });
                triggerDB.child("triggerVotesTotal").runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                    @Override
                    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                        int count = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);
                        mutableData.setValue(count + 1);

                        userDB.child(mUserId).child("changes").child(mImdbID).child("triggers").child(trigger.getTriggerName()).setValue(1);
                        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    }
                });
                userDB.child(mUserId).child("changes").child(mImdbID).child("triggers").child(trigger.getTriggerName()).setValue(1);
            }
        });

        holder.downButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {

                triggerDB.child("triggerVotesTotal").runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                    @Override
                    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                        int count = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);
                        mutableData.setValue(count + 1);

                        userDB.child(mUserId).child("changes").child(mImdbID).child("triggers").child(trigger.getTriggerName()).setValue(1);
                        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    }
                });

                userDB.child(mUserId).child("changes").child(mImdbID).child("triggers").child(trigger.getTriggerName()).setValue(1);
            }
        });
    }

    private void upButtonIsSelected(final ViewHolder holder, final Trigger trigger, final String mUserId) {
        holder.upButton.setOnClickListener(null);
        holder.downButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {
                triggerDB = movieDB.child(mImdbID).child("Triggers").child(trigger.getTriggerName());
                triggerDB.child("triggerVotesYes").runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                    @Override
                    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                        int count = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);
                        mutableData.setValue(count - 1);
                        userDB.child(mUserId).child("changes").child(mImdbID).child("triggers").child(trigger.getTriggerName()).setValue(-1);
                        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
               holder.downButton.getBackground().setAlpha(127);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
    private void downButtonIsSelected(final ViewHolder holder, final Trigger trigger, final String mUserId) {
        holder.downButton.setOnClickListener(null);
        holder.upButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {
                triggerDB = movieDB.child(mImdbID).child("Triggers").child(trigger.getTriggerName());
                triggerDB.child("triggerVotesYes").runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                    @Override
                    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                        int count = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);
                        mutableData.setValue(count + 1);
                        userDB.child(mUserId).child("changes").child(mImdbID).child("triggers").child(trigger.getTriggerName()).setValue(1);
                        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                holder.downButton.getBackground().setAlpha(127);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following things might help you.

- Use `android:stackFromBottom="true"` in the xml of your `ListView`
- Instead of using `mTriggerList.clear();` when updating, do not clear it and add the item to list only if the item does not already exist in the list.

Eg.

```
for(Trigger trigger: triggerSnapShot...){
    if (!mTriggerList.contains(trigger)){
        mTriggerList.add(trigger);
    }
}
```

You may need to override the `equals` method in the `Trigger` class in order to make the method `contains` work properly.

Comment: would it be mTriggerList or mResultList?  in what way would I override the trigger class?